# Use the 'new' keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model, ado.net

I´m trying to do a relationship between entities using ADO.

```
public class Banner
{
    public int IdBanner { get; set; }
    public string NameBanner { get; set; }
    public string Media { get; set; }

    public Country Country{ get; set; }
}

public class Country 
{
    public int IdCountry { get; set; }
    public string NameCountry { get; set; }
}
```

And in my another class (DAL), I have a method and this method I need to insert a properties inside Country Class, like my exemple:

```
public List<Banner> Listar()
{
            List<Banner> lista = new List<Banner>();

            using (SqlConnection conn = ConnectionDAL.GetConnection())
            {
                String sql = "BannerListar";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Banner obj = new Banner();

                            if (dr["IdBanner"] != DBNull.Value)
                                obj.IdBanner = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdBanner"]);

                            if (dr["NameBanner"] != DBNull.Value)
                                obj.NameBanner = dr["NameBanner"].ToString();

                            if (dr["Media"] != DBNull.Value)
                                obj.Media = dr["Media"].ToString();


                //HERE the problem
                            if (dr["NameCountry"] != DBNull.Value)
                                obj.Country.NameCountry = dr["NameCountry"].ToString();



                            lista.Add(obj);

                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                    }


                    return lista;

                }

            }

        }
```

When I do this show to me a erro like this: "Use the 'new' keyword to create an object instance"
How can I fix it?

Comment: On what line you get the error?

Comment: Here:
if (dr["NameCountry"] != DBNull.Value)
                                obj.Country.NameCountry = dr["NameCountry"].ToString();

Comment: At while the error is. Error is mainly because you are trying to create instance of some class without new key word.

Comment: can you post complete stacktrace ? are you getting all the values from the stored procedure ??

Comment: In procedure return to me "NameCountry".
I need to put the new keyword, but I don´t know where! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the object of class `Banner` but the object contained in the banner of class `Country` is not being created. So create it, before you use it. You can do this in default constructor of `Banner` class.

```
public class Banner
{
    public Banner() //Add the default constructor and initiate the Country object
    {
        Country = new Country();
    }
    public int IdBanner { get; set; }
    public string NameBanner { get; set; }
    public string Media { get; set; }

    public Country Country{ get; set; }
}
```

I have given the cause of possible problem and suggested a solution that will get rid of error with minimum effort and intentionally kept it simple for better understanding. You can extend this by explicitly passing the Country or passing null in place of Country or create `Country` Object and assign it to object in `Banner`.

Comment: While this looks clean, there would be a case when a banner does not have a country associated to it (say table column Banner.IdCountry was allowed to accept NULL in SQL). This would still give a valid country and not non-existent one to represent NULL from database.

Comment: I used your solution! tks!!

Comment: @vnikhil thanks, I pointed the possible cause of error and suggested the way to get rid of error to keep it simple and focus of the issue. I updated the answer by suggesting OP to tune as per requirements.

Answer (score 3):

you have to create object of Country class before intializing NameCountry

```
 if (dr["NameCountry"] != DBNull.Value)
   {
      Country country = new Country();
      country.NameCountry = dr["NameCountry"].ToString(); 
obj.Country = country;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Banner class Country is class property for the Country class. So if you add value to in this property first you need to create object for that class.

**Add below line :-**

```
obj.Country = new Country(); 
if (dr["NameCountry"] != DBNull.Value)
   obj.Country.NameCountry = dr["NameCountry"].ToString();
```